# Populating DataGridview from Excel with the selected sheet in ComboBox

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I'm initially populating my DataGridView with data from Excel Sheet.

```
  private void btnChooseAndRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        string fileExt = string.Empty;
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();//open dialog to choose file
        if (file.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)//if there is a file choosen by the user
        {
            filePath = file.FileName;//get the path of the file
            fileExt = Path.GetExtension(filePath);//get the file extension
            if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0 || fileExt.CompareTo(".xlsx") == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    cmbSheetName.Text = "";
                    cmbSheetName.Items.Clear();
                    string[] names = GetExcelSheetNames(file.FileName);
                    //Populate Combobox with Sheet names 
                    foreach (string name in names)
                    {
                        cmbSheetName.Items.Add(name);
                    }
                    DataTable dtExcel = new DataTable();
                    dtExcel = ReadExcel(filePath, fileExt); //read excel file
                    cmbSheetName.Visible = true;
                    lblFileName.Text = file.SafeFileName.ToString();
                    BindingSource theBindingSource = new BindingSource();
                    dgvViewData.Visible = true;
                    dgvViewData.DataSource = dtExcel;
                    //dgvViewData.ColumnDisplayIndexChanged = true;
                    //cmbSheetName_SelectedIndexChanged(sender, e);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please choose .xls or .xlsx file only.", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);//custom messageBox to show error
            }
        }
    }

 public DataTable ReadExcel(string fileName, string fileExt)
    {
        string conn = string.Empty;
        DataTable dtexcel = new DataTable();
        if (fileExt.CompareTo(".xls") == 0)//compare the extension of the file
            conn = @"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HRD=Yes;IMEX=1';";//for below excel 2007
        else
            conn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + fileName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1';";//for above excel 2007
        using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conn))
        {
            try
            {
                OleDbDataAdapter oleAdpt = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", con);//here we read data from sheet1
                oleAdpt.Fill(dtexcel);//fill excel data into dataTable
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
        return dtexcel;
    }
```

Which works perfectly fine, now the Excel file that I'm reading from has more than one sheets. 
[image]

I also have a combobox populating the Sheetnames.
[image]

What needs to happen is that when the user selects for example "Sheet5" from the combo I want to refresh the Gridview with the selected sheet details. How do I do this? How do I even know that all sheets are all in the Gridview?

Comment: Create a procedure than opens the Excel file and initializes a DataSet (or a List<DataTable>), with one DataTable per sheet. When you select a specific sheet, just change the DataGridView.DataSource.

Comment: @Graffito That sounds like it will work, can you please help further. Do i scrap all my read method? Or I can still edit it...If you have some code please share.

Comment: Just define dtexcel as a list<DataTable> (the variable should belong to the form and be initialized to null). In ReadExcel (that would return the List<DataTable>), loop on Sheets until you got an error/exception when you initialize *oleDbAdapt =  OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet"+sheetIndex+"1$]", con)*. Call ReadExcel only if dtexcel is null, otherwise the datatables are kept and reasy to be used as DataSource. Before processing another excel file, reset dtexcel to null.

Comment: @Graffito I did as you advised, now my problem is on looping the sheets while adding to the List<DataTable> ? Also do I loop while slecting using the oleAdpt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not test this thoroughly, but it appears to work correctly. Assuming you are using OLEDB... basically the code below uses a `DataSet` to hold all the worksheets. While gathering the worksheets I also create a simple `List<string>` to hold the names of each worksheet to display into the combo box. Since the worksheet and the combo box are added at the same time, we can use the combo boxes selected index to identify the proper worksheet (data table in the data set) to display. The names of worksheets have a “$” sign in their name. I removed this “$” when displayed to the combo box.

The code below is a form with a `DataGridView` to display the data tables, a `ComboBox` to select a data table and a `Label` to give info about the currently selected data table.  Hope this helps.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
  private string Excel07ConString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\YourFilePath\YourFile.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text'";
  string sheetName;
  DataSet ds;
  List<string> comboBoxData = new List<string>();

  public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();
    SetDataTablesFromExcel();
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    comboBox1.DataSource = comboBoxData;
    label1.Text = "TableName: " + ds.Tables[0].TableName + " has " + ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count + " rows";
  }

  private void SetDataTablesFromExcel() {
    ds = new DataSet();
    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(Excel07ConString)) {
      using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand()) {
        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter()) {
          cmd.Connection = con;
          con.Open();
          DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);

          for (int i = 0; i < dtExcelSchema.Rows.Count; i++) {
            sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[i]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" + sheetName + "]";
            oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            oda.Fill(dt);
            dt.TableName = sheetName;
            comboBoxData.Add(sheetName.Replace("$", ""));
            ds.Tables.Add(dt);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int index = comboBox1.SelectedIndex;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[index];
    label1.Text = "TableName: " + ds.Tables[index].TableName + " has " + ds.Tables[index].Rows.Count + " rows";
  }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!!